# What constitutes a redundant tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

In the suggested edits queue I have come across proposed tag deletions with the comment "removed redundant tags." I usually skip these as I am not clear on what is considered good or bad in tag repetition. Examples of cases include things like:

> [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) [ios5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios5) [ios5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios5.1)

or

> [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) [sql-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) [sql-server-2012-express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012-express)

It has been my understanding that there's nothing wrong with tagging a question with the general and more specific tag of a technology—i.e. [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8). Is this wrong? What is considered duplication that would warrant removal in the suggested edits queue?

Comment: I tend to skip a lot of tag edits but I'm not sure that having both the 5 and 5.1 tags in the first example is useful, at least not without context.

Comment: It would be helpful to see examples of what IS considered redundant and should be removed, even more than what is NOT considered redundant.

Comment: I agree. I'm sure someone with more experience with these edits will chime in.

Comment: A tag which there are better tag that fulfills the purpose of putting the question in front of those that can answer it. In other words: a tag that doesn't improve the probabilities of the question being answered.

Answer (score 7):

I think (and someone will correct me if I'm wrong) the philosophy here is that the smallest number of tags is best. The additional tags are there for cases where the problem being described is specific to one version of the language or product.

When PHP 7.0 was released, for example, there was a lot of new syntax and a resulting increase in the use of the  [php-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7) tag for questions involving those changes. But if someone tags a question with  [php-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7) just because it's the version they're using, it doesn't add any value and should be left out. (Now that PHP 7 has matured and become more mainstream, that tag is much less common.)

Editing to add that the [php-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7) questions would also have been tagged with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) as well, or they wouldn't have been seen by nearly as many people.

Comment: "least number of tags is best" not necessarily, my rule of thumb is: least number of tags that doesn't make the question likely to be answered the best. Selecting the tags should be like selecting equipment for a Mission Impossible mission, you don't want to be dragged down by anything that you don't need and would definitively want that that will help with the mission.

Comment: *"the least number of tags is best"* Why? The actual philosophy is that useless tags are discouraged, but that doesn't have anything to do with minimizing the total number of tags. The only hard limit is 5, but there's nothing wrong with using all 5 slots.

Comment: Fun numbers for you @CodyGray: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/213287/count-of-questions-per-amount-of-tags-and-if-they-are-answered-or-not the more tags you use, the more likely your question is left unanswered. I'm not advocating for less tags, but as you said useless tag. It seems that it's more likely that you use useless tags the more tags you use, therefore the less likely you would get an answer (to be fair, my query doesn't count tags on the initial revision, so, grain of salt).

Comment: @Braiam interesting numbers. I checked SU, SF, Apple, and Ubuntu sites. They all hold to this pattern for questions with more than 2 tags (1 and 2 seem to swap places on a couple of sites.)

Comment: I presume because people that uses more tags are just doing crap shots: to see what sticks. But for some reasons, they are literal crap shots as they use as many tags that wouldn't help them to answer their questions.

Comment: re using php-7 and unless I'm misunderstanding you: actually, it should be the most *specific* tag that is chosen. If the question is about a php-7 feature of the language, such as yield from, php-7 should of course be used, not removed. I believe this is consistent with usage across other versioned tags.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier yes that's what I'm saying: that in cases where the question is about a feature specific to PHP 7, using the php-7 tag would be appropriate. But the php tag should also be used to ensure the relevant audience sees the question.

Comment: The problem of having "features specific to a version" is that it's virtually impossible that the feature will be present in only one interaction of the software (cc @FélixGagnon-Grenier). I bet 10 to 1 to anyone that feels that "yield from" will not be present on php 8, 9, 10, 11, ...

Comment: @Braiam yes I suppose "a feature new to PHP 7" instead of "specific to" would be a better way to put it, which was what I was getting at when I said "Now that PHP 7 has matured and become more mainstream, that tag is much less common."

Answer (score 4):

- Is the question specific to the used tag?
- Is the used tag as narrow as possible?
- Is the tag required to reach a sizeable audience?

Those are the criteria by which you should judge tags.

Here's why:

- If the question is not specific to the tag, then the tag provides no useful information and is just noise.

  I see many users tag their questions with stuff like [ios5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios5.1) just because they happen to be on iOS 5.1, even though their question is equally applicable to iOS 4 or 6. This is essentially the same as tagging your question [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) just because you happen to be using XCode to develop the code that you're having trouble with. They could've tagged their question with [notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) or [ios5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios5.0.1) instead and it would make no difference.
  On the other hand, even though tags like [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) are by themselves incredibly broad, it *does* make a difference if that were switched out for [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) or [applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript). If you disagree, go look at some questions tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). ;)
- If the tag is not as narrow as possible, then it leaves out some important information.

  Let's say your code was working fine on iOS 5.0, but now you get whatever error on iOS 5.1. That's important information which makes a difference for the question.
- Now, sadly there is a slight problem with the above rule: If do your homework, narrow down your problem as much as possible and tag your question [ios5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios5.1)[c99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c99), then... good luck getting anyone to see it. Those two tags combined have a whopping 272 users following them. [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) has 200'000, [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) has 100'000.

  So for the simply sake of reaching an audience, I would argue that it is okay to tag your question [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)[c99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c99) or [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)[ios5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios5.1) because both tags serve a different purpose.
  However, it is certainly *not* okay to have [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)[ios5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios5)[ios5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios5.1) - the most general of those is okay to reach an audience and the most narrow applicable one is okay to provide accurate information, but the rest has to go.

Comment: Agree completely. In the example I gave in my answer, the questions would be tagged with php and php-7 to increase the audience.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, based on the examples, is really about whether version tags are appropriate. In theory, version tags are useful because they bring up issues specific to a version. However, in practice, they are unhelpful. Consider this question:

[How to escape slash in url path in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369653/how-to-escape-slash-in-url-path-in-python)

The asker tagged it with both [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [python-2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6), presumably because that's what he's using. But the question has absolutely nothing to do with a particular version of the Python programming language. Anyone looking to filter on [python-2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6) due to interest in that version in particular is going to be disappointed.  Therefore it is no different than if the asker had simply left the version tag out.

So unless mods are vigilant in removing version tags from posts where they do not apply, they will remain useless. And it is a non-trivial task: I would say that misuse greatly outnumbers correct use, based on a random sampling.

The best thing to do, in my opinion, is to convert version tags to the unversioned tag sitewide, which means marking them redundant. And make it incumbent upon the asker to specify which version they are using, when appropriate, in the title and/or body rather than in tags.